# Can I get a Bitcoin credit card?

Tags: bitcoin-credit-card

I saw a video on youtube about a card for Bitcoin, is there a legit card service?

(I am a complete noob in bitcoin so please mention links in the answers)

Comment: There are no existing "credit" cards out there. Only debit cards. Almost all of the bitcoin debit cards existing nowadays are rebrandings of the "MyChoiceCorporate" debit card. I honestly can't name one that doesn't use MCC.

Answer (score 2):

Two card services that I know of are [xapo](https://xapo.com/card/) and [e-coin](https://www.e-coin.io/) (debit) cards. I know people that used them successfully and as far as I can tell are legit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! , can you tell me if i can use the card your mentioned anywhere like a common Master or Visa card (I live in Sri Lanka & Bitcoin is not famous here yet & that's why i'm asking)

Comment: That is the idea: you can use it anywhere you could use a card. For example, the e-coin card is mastercard so it will be accepted everywhere a mastercard is accepted. Both cards work in several European countries. I cannot be certain but I don't believe you will have issues in Sri Lanka.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [xapo](http://xapo.com). The card works great. There is a Bitcoin wallet app where you can store bitcoins. The debit card just spends what you have in your wallet.

[Bitstamp](http://bitstamp.net) which is an exchange for buying coins also provide debit cards. I haven't used the card but bitstamp is a well known reputable exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! , can you tell me if i can use the card your mentioned anywhere like a common Master or Visa card (I live in Sri Lanka & Bitcoin is not famous here yet & that's why i'm asking)

Comment: The xapo card is a visa debit. As far as I know you can use it anywhere visa works. I have never had any problems.

Comment: bitstamp solution is terrible. they have very low withdrawal limit per month. and when I made the product choice it was not written there. only deposit limit that are elevated when they do aditional KYC/AML. In summary beware of that. Everything else bitstamp does is OK, debit card is not.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of the following Bitcoin cards:

- [The Shift Card](https://www.shiftpayments.com/), which is a Visa debit card that can [integrate with a Coinbase account](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2228646-the-shift-card)
- [The BitPay Card](https://bitpay.com/visa/), which is a Visa debit card
- [The Xapo Bitcoin Debit Card](https://xapo.com/card/)